# Modify sender address in mail plugin

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-8

I'm using the `notify_entity` module for Drupal 8 and want to change the mail address used for the `from` value.
I'm trying to do it using `hook_mail_alt r` but it doesn't work, Drupal still send mail with the default administrator mail address... Am I doing something wrong? Or there is another way to do this?
Thanks.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter()
 */
function notify_entity_mail_alter(&$message){
  $from = "foo@bar.com";
  $message['from'] = $from;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They should be changed like this

```
  $message['headers']['Return-Path'] = 'user@email.com';
  $message['headers']['Sender'] = 'user@email.com';
  $message['headers']['From'] = 'Site name';
  $message['headers']['Reply-to'] = 'user@email.com';
```

Also note it seems you are modifying (hacking) the `notify_entity` module right ? You should not do that! If you update it or someone else updates this drupal installation in the future you might end up losing the changes and not realize it ...

You should create your own module and implement the `hook_mail_alter` and name your function `MYMODULE_mail_alter()`

Just today I had to do this and stumbled upon your question here it is a very simple module that does exactly what you want  https://github.com/GiorgosK/mail_alter_headers. 
NOTE: you have to modify the .module file with your own details or comment out `//` the ones you don't want to modify.